# Airflow 2.0 - Task stuck in queued state even though pool slots available

Tags: redis, celery, airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x

python dependencies:

- apache-airflow==2.1.3
- redis==3.5.3
- celery==4.4.7

airflow config:

- core.parallelism = 1000
- core.dag_concurrency = 400
- core.max_active_runs_per_dag = 1
- celery.worker_concurrency = 6
- celery.broker_url = redis
- celery.result_backend = mysql

Facing this issue after upgrade to airflow 2.0

Not all tasks stuck in "queued" state, only 1 task stuck at a time (out of 100+).

Sometimes tasks stuck in "running" state also.

This issue happens once in 1-2 days.

This happens even though pool slots available to use (Slots = 128, Running slots = 0, Queued slots = 1)

As per worker logs (for both stuck tasks and normal tasks):

```
INFO/MainProcess] Received task: airflow.executors.celery_executor.execute_command[066398d7-98e0-4f17-bd2b-93ae36438577]
INFO/ForkPoolWorker-6] Executing command in Celery: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'dag_name', 'task01', '2021-10-26T14:00:00+00:00', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--subdir', '/dag_dir/dag.py']
```

I see below log for all normal working tasks, this is missing for the stuck tasks:

```
WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Running <TaskInstance: dag.task02 2021-10-26T14:00:00+00:00 [queued]> on host worker02.localdomain
```

Comment: Usually that happens when the queue name is not correct.

Comment: @floating_hammer I am using "default" queue, if there would have been some issue with queue name then no task would execute rite? but in this case only 1 task stucks at a time

Comment: Humm - There is no such thing as a default queue. When you start the worker you need to give a queue name like this  `airflow queue -q my_queue`. In the DAG task you need to give `my_queue` in the queue name parameter. That will work.

Comment: Using airflow default config for queue name : operators.default_queue = default

Comment: Update: Observed that "queued" task is missing in redis queue itself

Comment: celery_taskmeta.status is "STARTED"

Comment: Did anyone find a solution?